# Angular2, RxJS Subject http request - On error request wont fire again

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, observable, subject-observer

I have an issue when receiving an http error response (422 validation error from backend).

Once an http error response is received, I can't fire the request again (on button click).

1) I have a subject property, and I call .next(whatEverDataForTheRequest), in order to kick of the request to the API.

2) In the constructor I subscribe to the subject (.asObservable), and here everything goes fine whenever the response is succesfull, but not when an error happens.

Code is currently like this:

```
// Properties -> Subject + Observable, used when button is clicked
private saveBookingSubject: Subject<BookingUpdateInterface> = new Subject<BookingUpdateInterface>();
private saveBookingObservable = this.saveBookingSubject.asObservable();
```

When button is clicked, I create a payload/object and pass in like this:

```
this.saveBookingSubject.next(payload)
```

Then in the constructor, I have the following code which gets triggered when .next gets called.

```
const sub = this.saveBookingObservable.pipe(
  tap(data => {
    this.bookingError = null;
    this.dialogCanClose = false;
  }),
  debounceTime(500),
  switchMap(booking => {
    return this.bookingService.update(booking).pipe(catchError(error => throwError(error)));
  })
).subscribe((response: any) => {
  // This works - Called on success
  console.log('ok', response);
}, (http: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  // This works - Gets called on error
  console.log(http);
});
```

Successful request works as intended - But when an error is received from backend, then the call to:

```
this.saveBookingSubject.next(payload)
```

...is completely ignored, whenever the button gets clicked -> And the subscription logic never kicks in.

What am I missing here? (I do unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy)

Thanks!

---

EDIT EDIT - WORKING EXAMPLE (as posted by Martin)

```
const sub = this.saveBookingObservable.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  switchMap(booking => {
    return this.bookingService.update(booking).pipe(
      catchError(httpError => {
        this.bookingError = httpError.error.data;
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }),
  retry(1)
).subscribe((response: any) => {
    // Handle success
  }
});
```

Comment: It's look not full codes,I can't reproduction the problem , so I guess maybe you need [retry](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/retry) operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have comes down to ["The Observable contract"](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html). One chain can emit only one error notification so when your `this.bookingService.update` emits an error the chain is disposed (unsubscribed). Emitting more `next` notifications from `saveBookingObservable` has therefore no effect.

Depending on what you want exactly you want to do it seems like you could just append `retry()` after `switchMap()` that will automatically resubscribe.

Comment: Hi Martin - You are absolutely right, appending retry(1), made the whole thing behave as expected. I guessed the contract wasn't broken, but clearly I was wrong there - Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Adding `retry` without any count lets the user try any number of times on click. Also the sequence of adding `retry` after `switchMap` is important.